# how to use selectors in redux app with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, redux, reselect

I try to use `selectors` from reselect library in my Redux app.

my selectors file looks:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const postsSelectors = state => state.global.posts.allPostse;

export const getPosts = createSelector(
  [ postsSelectors ],
  (posts) => posts
);
```

and then I try to use in my component, like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: getPosts(state),
});
```

When I try to compile all of this, I got this error:

[image]

I'm guessing that with how I declare types for props, which currently looks like that:

```
interface Props{
 posts(state: any): any
 loadStories(): void;
};
```

Help me please resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript is not expecting an array for the first argument. Just pass in your selector functions as arguments to createSelector, as in

```
export const getPosts = createSelector(
  postsSelectors,
  (posts) => posts
);
```

Answer (score 12):

An example with more **types**:

1. Describe types

```js
type TPostData = {
  type: string;
};

type TPostsState = TPostData[];

type TState = {
  posts: TPostsState;
};
```

2. Create selectors

```js
// get all posts
export const selectPosts = (state: TState): TPostsState => state.posts;

// get new posts
export const selectNewPosts = createSelector<
  TState,
  TPostsState,
  TPostData[]>(
    selectPosts,
    (posts) => posts.filter(({ type }) => type === 'new'),
  );
```

Result: You've got all posts with type parameter 'new'.

Answer (score 3):

In the `reselect@4.1.5` generics typing signature slightly changed if you're using the `typescript@≥4.2`. So now it needs to be specified as: `createSelector<Selectors extends SelectorArray, Result>`

```
<Selectors extends SelectorArray, Result>

export type Selector<
  // The state can be anything
  State = any,
  // The result will be inferred
  Result = unknown,
  // There are either 0 params, or N params
  Params extends never | readonly any[] = any[]
  // If there are 0 params, type the function as just State in, Result out.
  // Otherwise, type it as State + Params in, Result out.
> = [Params] extends [never]
  ? (state: State) => Result
  : (state: State, ...params: Params) => Result

export type SelectorArray = ReadonlyArray<Selector>
```

Example:

```
// get all posts
export const selectPosts = (state: TState): TPostsState => state.posts;

// get new posts
export const selectNewPosts = createSelector<
  [Selector<TState, TPostsState>],
  TPostData[]
>(
    selectPosts,
    (posts) => posts.filter(({ type }) => type === 'new'),
  );
```

But in general, for the newer TS, *you should not specify types manually now, as they will be automatically inferred.*

If you're getting **`TS4023: Exported variable 'X' has or is using the name '$CombinedState' from external module`**, please refer to the Stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43901135/10963661 or try to set `"declaration": false` compiler option in the `tsconfig.json` file.