# TS4023: Exported Variable <x> has or is using name <y> from external module but cannot be named

Tags: typescript, types, module, declaration, type-inference

I've seen this answered before, but they don't seem to cover this specific use case (or they don't work/help)

```
import {Route} from 'vue-router';


export const detailRoute = {
  path: '/detail/:id',
  component: Detail,
  props: (route: Route) => ({
    state: route.query.state
  })
};
```

detailRoute uses Route, which I am importing, but I guess as a named import {Route} it doesn't work? Is there a different/better way to do this that will work? I tried `export {Route};` as well, but that didn't help.

tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "ES2015",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./types",
        "lib": [
          "DOM",
          "ES2017",
          "DOM.Iterable",
          "ScriptHost"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "./client",
        "paths": {
          "styles/*": ["./app/core/styles/*"],
          "core/*": ["./app/core/*"],
          "components/*": ["./app/components/*"],
          "containers/*": ["./app/containers/*"],
          "assets/*": ["./assets/*"],
          "config/*": ["./config/*"]
        }
      }
    }
```

Exact error:

`TS4023: Exported variable 'detailRoute' has or is using name 'Route' from external module "/Users/chris/<projectname>/node_modules/vue-router/types/router" but cannot be named.`

Comment: See this solution from GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5711

Comment: Thanks, that's where I started, but it didn't seem to help, or I'm missing something. I imported {Route}, I tried exporting {Route}, I don't know what else I can do to say "Route is in this".

Comment: I have not been able to recreate your issue. I am using TypeScript 2.3 and commonjs modules. What are you using?

Comment: ES6 modules with Node resolution, and declaration = true;

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The compiler is failing to figure out the exact shape of `detailRoute`, because it does not know the shape of `Route`.

#### Option 1

One way around this is to import `Route` from its source, thereby providing the information that the compiler needs to determine the shape of `detailRoute`.

```
import { Route } from "./../node_modules/vue-router/types/router";

export const detailRoute = {
  props: (route: Route) => null,
};
```

Since [the `index.d.ts` file in `vue-router`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/bce38f89710612149d26215c110cfab113a67803/types) (which you were importing in the question) re-exports `Route`, it does not provide the *direct* reference to `Route` that the compiler needed.

#### Option 2

Another option is to opt `detailRoute` out of static typing altogether.

```
import { Route } from 'vue-router'; // index.d.ts

export const detailRoute: any = {
  props: (route: Route) => null,
};
```

Since `any` opts-out of static typing, the compiler does not need to figure out the shape of `detailRoute`.

#### Option 3

A further is option is what you did in your own answer. Since you provided the type annotation, the compiler again does not need to figure out the shape of `detailRoute`.

```
import { Route, RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'; // index.d.ts

export const detailRoute: RouteConfig = {
  props: (route: Route) => null,
};
```

#### See also

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5711

> When trying to emit [the module], the compiler needs to write an object type literal... representing the shape of the module. But there isn't a name in scope that refers directly to [Route], so the type "cannot be named" and there's an error.
>
> If you add [a direct] import of [Route]... the error should go away.

Answer (score 21):

For me it this issue was because I was trying to build a library doing:

```
interface Props {...};
const MyComponent = ({...}:Props)=>{<>...</>}
```

I changed to:

```
type Props = {...};
```

Issue resolved.

Comment: This is weird, but yeah it fixed it for me.

Comment: It would be interesting to understand why it fixes the problem

Comment: This fixed it for me too, but it's weird for sure

Comment: You could also change it to export interface Props {...}; But still weird that TypeScript is able to use the type, but not the interface

Comment: so why do types work but not interfaces? I thought they were interchangeable.

*late edit*: this might have to do with the way `dynamic()` itself is typed. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69353026/3873510).

Answer (score 9):

Apparently this is the solution to my problem:

```
  import {Route, RouteConfig} from 'vue-router';


  export const detailRoute: RouteConfig = {
    path: '/detail/:id',
    component: Detail,
    props: (route: Route) => ({
      state: route.query.state
    })
  };
```

Specifying that detailRoute was a RouteConfig (which in turn uses Route) solved the problem. I must have misunderstood how this is supposed to work, but this fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this when typing a rootReducer, in case anyone else is doing the same. I was importing typed reducers that were composed of other types (state, actions) that I had not also exported.

**Short answer**: export all your **action** and **state** types from the reducers!

Composite types seem not to work to well when their parts are not also exported and you rely on type inference. In this case, inferring the type of the rootReducer (which would be too much to explicitly type if you have more than just a few reducers).

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ typedReducerA, typedReducerB, ... }
```

Comment: I was also dealing with reducer issues, and the solution for me was to remove the unique symbol from `RootState` before attempting to extend it. The solution for me was: `Subtract<RootState, CombinedState<{}>>`. `Subtract` comes from the `utility-types` npm package

Answer (score 5):

An extension to this question for those looking for an answer.

With the following conditions:

###### Typescript

Version installed: `^4.8.3`

###### TSConfig

```json
{
  "module": "NodeNext",
  "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
}
```

###### package.json

```json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

###### Layout

```
src/lib/types.ts      // contains all type defs
src/lib/something.ts  // contains type def consumption and error
```

I encountered this issue with my own library.

###### The code

1. Consumed an exported type (`Box`)
2. Exported type consumed an unexported type (`Dimension`)
3. Consuming exported type via implicit type (no explicit `: SomeType` annotation)
4. Error saying that `Box` is [named but can't be] -- (read: "I can't find the name of something")

###### The reason

Typescript is looking for the type within `Box` called `Dimension`, and failed. "Cannot be named" is an unclear error, but it basically means "Yo, I have no clue what's in this thing" from the context in which it was thrown.

###### My solution

Export the nested type.

```js
export interface Box {
  width: Dimension;
}

interface Dimension {
  size: number;
  meta: any;
}
```

Should become

```js
export interface Box {
  width: Dimension;
}

// Update this:
//     interface Dimension {
// To this:
export interface Dimension {
  size: number;
  meta: any;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have already pointed out, this is indeed caused by referencing locally imported types.

Without this [commit](https://github.com/gajus/roarr/commit/5c4e8d373db96c91ee3b0cd7c543ed72bf158791):

```
- type JsonObject = {
+ export type JsonObject = {
```

My applications started to break with an error:

```
Error: @contra/utilities:build: src/Logger.ts(3,14): error TS4023: Exported variable 'Logger' has or is using name 'JsonObject' from external module "/home/github/actions-runner/_work/gaia/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/roarr@7.18.0/node_modules/roarr/dist/types" but cannot be named.
Error: @contra/utilities:build: src/Logger.ts(3,14): error TS7056: The inferred type of this node exceeds the maximum length the compiler will serialize. An explicit type annotation is needed.
```

Exporting `JsonObject` made that error go away.

What's exceptionally strange is that if you look at the [origin of the error](https://github.com/gajus/roarr/blob/5c4e8d373db96c91ee3b0cd7c543ed72bf158791/src/types.ts#L3-L18), `JsonObject` then references `JsonValue`, which is also not exported publicly. But unlike `JsonObject`, this is causing no issues.

```
type JsonValue =
  | JsonObject
  | JsonValue[]
  | boolean
  | number
  | string
  | readonly JsonValue[]
  | null
  | undefined;

/**
 * @public
 */
export type JsonObject = {
  [k: string]: JsonValue;
};
```

Feels like a bug in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) or a poorly documented behavior.

If you are an author of the package from which the error originates, the solution is to export the type that's causing the error.

Comment: That solves it, no need to move the definitions anywhere, simply exporting was enough. And indeed, it’s only an issue for some types and not others. I recall seeing an explanation on some TS GH issue, but forgot what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be caused by having local type definitions.

```
type ABC = {abc: number};
export const function = (): ABC => { return {abc: 123}};
```

Move the type definitions to a separate file and import them

```
//types.ts
export type ABC = {abc: number};

//function.ts
import {ABC} from "./types";
export const function = (): ABC => { return {abc: 123}};
```

Comment: Same thing, but with enum. Moving to a separate file helped.

Answer (score -3):

Adding a return type fixed the problem for me

```
export const test_setUpApp = async (args?: {
    fixtureData: SomeType;
}) => {
    ....
    }
```

Gave me the error with `SomeType`
This fixed the problem:

```
export const test_setUpApp = async (args?: {
    fixtureData: SomeType;
}):Promise<ReturnType> => {
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add this into `tsconfig.json`

```
compilerOptions: {
  ...
  "declaration": false,
  "emitDeclarationOnly": false
}
```

Comment: This could use a bit of explanation.