# NextJS dynamic import issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm facing a really strange issue with `dynamic` import from `NextJS`.

I'm importing a component like so:

```
const Spinner = dynamic(() => import('components/ui/Spinner').then(mod => mod.Spinner))
```

And the `Spinner.tsx` is

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import PulseLoader from 'react-spinners/PulseLoader'

import {FadeHOC} from '.'
import theme from 'utils/theme'


interface Props {
  inline?: boolean
}

const TIMEOUT = 1000

export const Spinner = ({inline}: Props) => {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const timeout = setTimeout(
      () => setShow(true),
      TIMEOUT
    )
    
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, [])

  return (
    show
      ? <FadeHOC>
          <PulseLoader size={10} margin={3} color={theme.color} css={inline ? 'margin-left: 14px;' : 'display: block; text-align: center; margin: 100px auto;'} />
        </FadeHOC>
      : null
  )
}
```

And on the `dynamic` import statement I get a `TypeScript` complaint:

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<(({ inline }: Props) => JSX.Element) | ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.
  Type '() => Promise<(({ inline }: Props) => JSX.Element) | ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; }>' is not assignable to type '() => LoaderComponent<{}>'.
    Type 'Promise<(({ inline }: Props) => Element) | ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; }>' is not assignable to type 'LoaderComponent<{}>'.
      Type '(({ inline }: Props) => Element) | ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | { default: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
        Type '({ inline }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | { default: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
          Type '({ inline }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
            Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
              Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' has no properties in common with type 'Props'.ts(2345)
```

I can't figure out what the complaint is about, and I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Try defining `Spinner` like this: ```export const Spinner: React.FC<Props> = ({inline}) => {```

Comment: Hey, this actually worked. What's the magic here? Is this simply telling Typescript that my Spinner is indeed a functional component? How come can't Typescript infer that? After all, in the error it does see that I'm providing a function that returns a `JSX.Element`...

Comment: It is simply because a function returning `JSX.Element` is not truly a functional component (according to TS at least). It mostly doesn't work in case of the components having props.

Comment: Thanks @brc-dd would be nice if you posted this as an answer!

Answer (score 16):

`dynamic` is typed like that:

```
export default function dynamic<P = {}>(dynamicOptions: DynamicOptions<P> | Loader<P>, options?: DynamicOptions<P>): React.ComponentType<P>;
```

where P is props of the imported component

So, dynamic expects to get `Loader<P>` = `LoaderComponent<P>` = `Promise<React.ComponentType<P>`

You just need to tell him what the props are. Like this:

```
const Spinner = dynamic<{ inline?: boolean }>(
  () => import('components/ui/Spinner').then(mod => mod.Spinner)
)
```

or

```
import { Spinner as StaticSpinner } from 'components/ui/Spinner'

const Spinner = dynamic<React.ComponentProps<typeof StaticSpinner>>(
  () => import('components/ui/Spinner').then(mod => mod.Spinner)
)
```

or make Props as exported and then:

```
import { Props as SpinnerProps } from 'components/ui/Spinner'

const Spinner = dynamic<SpinnerProps>(
  () => import('components/ui/Spinner').then(mod => mod.Spinner)
)
```

Comment: TL;DR: If you use `typescript`, pass `SpinnerProps` to `dynamic`. Reason is `<DynamicSpinner />`  haven't know what is it props yet.

Comment: We've got some components that we import like this `import { Cardshell } from '@bit/ds.components.cardshell';`. Will imports like this work with `dynamic`?

Comment: Barrel file + generics in props type = you are out of luck

Answer (score 0):

@brc-dd is right, just define the component with `React.FC` type,

`export const Spinner: React.FC<Props> = ({inline}) => {}`

although small explanation why it works like that:

`dynamic` is typed like that:

```
export default function dynamic<P = {}>(dynamicOptions: DynamicOptions<P> | Loader<P>, options?: DynamicOptions<P>): React.ComponentType<P>;
```

So it expects you to return `React.ComponentType<P>` and it means:

```
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | FunctionComponent<P>;
```

and `FunctionComponent` is:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }
```

So you have to have props with `children` key. If you don't want to mess up your component interface and it's actually not accepting children then you can just type `children?: never;` in component Props interface.