# Why do Images suddenly jump to cover full screen when changing routes in Next

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I am building a website using Next and Typescript. I am using the following packages:

1. Framer-motion for page transitions
2. Gsap for simpler animations

When I set the images using the following:

```
<Link>
    <div className={`figureContainer ${styles.figureContainer}>
        <Image layout="fill" objectFit="contain" src={lockIcon} alt="scx figure" priority={index === 0? true : false } />
        <div className={styles.menuTitle}>{item}</div>
     </div>
</Link>
```

and in the CSS the figure container class has the following base style:

```css
.figureContainer{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: filter 0.4s;
}
```

When I click a link to go to the store page, on localhost it works perfectly fine but when I deployed it to vercel and tried the same thing at first everything looks like it works but the Images jump to fill the screen when I change routes.
Almost as if I set `position: absolute` on images and `relative` on the body with no other intermediary parent being set to `relative`.

This only happens when I change routes on the vercel app: https://scx-landing-revamp-6eid5catf-tochibedford.vercel.app/ why does this happen? how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are doing great, I was facing the same issue (using next/image + FramerMotion) and I fixed it today by abstracting all the content in my `pages/index.tsx` into a IndexScreen.tsx file and then dynamically importing it using:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const IndexScreen = dynamic<IndexScreenProps>(() => import('@/screens/indexScreen').then(mod => mod.IndexScreen), {
    ssr: false,
});
```

Not sure if it's the best to do, but it worked!

Here is some reference docs that helped me:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import
In case you are using TypeScript: [NextJS dynamic import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289518/nextjs-dynamic-import-issue)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, i've been looking for a solution to this. What exactly do you mean by "content", the images themselves? or the entire page/component?

Comment: Check how I imported IndexScreen here: https://github.com/Marceliux/JardinBinario/blob/main/src/pages/index.tsx, previously I had all the content in IndexScreen inside the index.tsx file, let me know if that answers your question! Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey @marceliux this Actually worked. I haven't had time to implement it till today. and it worked perfectly. All I had to do was abstract away the index page also. cheers