# typescript not inferring types

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a project that seems my `tsconfig.json` have some missing configuration for inferring types.

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "lib",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "lib/**/*.spec.tsx",
    "lib/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "lib/settings/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And I have this error bellow:

[image]

To solve, I had to import `AnyStyledComponent` manually as can see bellow:

[image]

I am missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TS4023: Exported Variable <x> has or is using name <y> from external module but cannot be named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900035/ts4023-exported-variable-x-has-or-is-using-name-y-from-external-module-but)

Comment: I would try to add the include property in the `tsconfig.json` and let typescript include your lib/src folder

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem has to do with [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5711)

Comment: Hi, link-only answers are not very useful because if the link referenced is deleted, then the answer is gone. Please expand upon this. Thank you